# Spring Boot test is not reaching the MySql database

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-test

### Hey guys,

I am doing some testing for a small spring boot application which I am writing in Kotlin. I am using a MySql database for this project with jdbc. Everything is running on Docker.

I am currently testing my controller and I am facing some issues with my DB connection. My tests are always failing, this is the message I get every-time : `Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

#### Weird Problem

So it seems like the application is not connecting to the DB, but actually it is only not connecting in the testing scope. When I request this same url in the browser, I get no issues. What I currently think is that there is some miss-configuration which makes the test connection to the DB fail. But I don’t know where the issue could be.

Also, if I run a test against an endpoint which does not query the DB it also passes. So the DB is running since I can get the desired results when I use `curl`, for example. It only fails when I run the tests.

#### My Code

My tests look like this

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class AdAccountControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Test
    fun `we should get the ad-accounts`() {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/ad-account"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andDo(print())
    }
}
```

My application.properties looks like this:

```
mysql.database.host=database
mysql.database.port=3306
mysql.database.db=application
mysql.database.user=root
mysql.database.password=root

logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

My webAuthenticatior

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class WebAuthenticationConfigurator : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    private val dataSource: DataSource? = null

    @Autowired
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select email as username, password_hash as password, 1 from user where email=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email as username, 'ADMIN' as role from user where email=?")
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and().cors().disable()
    }
}
```

My datasource

```java
@Configuration
open class AuthenticationDataSource {

    @Value("\${mysql.database.host}")
    private val databaseHost: String? = null

    @Value("\${mysql.database.port}")
    private val databasePort: String? = null

    @Value("\${mysql.database.db}")
    private val databaseName: String? = null

    @Value("\${mysql.database.user}")
    private val databaseUser: String? = null

    @Value("\${mysql.database.password}")
    private val databasePassword: String? = null

    @Bean
    open fun getDataSource(): DataSource? {
        val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:mysql://$databaseHost:$databasePort/$databaseName")
        dataSourceBuilder.username(databaseUser)
        dataSourceBuilder.password(databasePassword)
        return dataSourceBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I think that its clear that my test environment is not being able to establish a connection with the DB, do I have to configure something extra to get this working with the tests?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you really want to connect to a database in your Tests? Did you consoder using an h2 or similiar for your Tests? External dependencies (not talking about libraries here) should be avoided in tests

Comment: You are suggesting using an H2 database only for testing? This would mean creating all the mysql table schemas in the new H2 database. I would also add a new dependency to the project: h2, and only for testing. Honestly I considered it but I am not sure if the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: Well, the h2 dependency would of course only have scope test and not be packaged with your jar. For the database initialization, its pretty common to have tools like Flyway to initialize the database for you, which means the database initialization scripts are with your project. This also helps other people getting started with your project faster. And of course it helps to write code that isn't hardly coupled to one RBMS.
If you keep requiring an external database in your tests, you won't be able to build your application on a server that has no access to it for example.

Comment: That’s why everything is containerised. I provide a container with mysql DB and initialise it the first time the container is created. 
Still H2 in an external DB no? I would be exchanging one dependency  for another and in this case, just for the test

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my approach. It had all to do with the `application.properties`. My `mysql.database.host` was having an incorrect value. The value of the host was the one that is used inside the containers.  Since the tests where being called from outside the scope of the container, the application was not reaching the export database.